# How to create JSON object into array using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

How to create `JSON Object` using jQuery?

I have a `JSON Object` in below format:

```
{

    "1":{
        "c_roleid":null,
        "ObjectID":1,
        "c_appname":"Default",
        "c_display":true,
        "c_add":null,
        "c_edit":null,
        "c_delete":null,
        "c_execute":null,
        "c_isdefault":null,
        "c_rolepermissionid":null,
        "c_objecttype":1
    }
}
```

How can I create JSON object in array for above format.

How to get data as array format into `web API`?

Comment: show what you have tried so far?

Comment: This question is not possible to parse in English. Maybe not best language but sadly is what we parse. Please try to communicate what your goal is. Array of what? Array in JSON? Array in JavaScript? Why you want array? For what?

Answer (score 2):

Edit: This is for your question "How to create JSON object using jQuery?"

```
var json = '{

        "1":{
            "c_roleid":null,
            "ObjectID":1,
            "c_appname":"Default",
            "c_display":true,
            "c_add":null,
            "c_edit":null,
            "c_delete":null,
            "c_execute":null,
            "c_isdefault":null,
            "c_rolepermissionid":null,
            "c_objecttype":1
        }
    }'
var obj = $.parseJSON(json);
```

Comment: Ok. I do it. But How I get data from Web Api in Array Format?

Comment: I don't understand what that means. You can parse JSON from a web API like this: `$.getJSON("url_with_json_here", function(data){
 /* do something */
});`. What do you mean by Array Format?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have a JSON data as

```
var json = '{

        "1":{
            "c_roleid":null,
            "ObjectID":1,
            "c_appname":"Default",
            "c_display":true,
            "c_add":null,
            "c_edit":null,
            "c_delete":null,
            "c_execute":null,
            "c_isdefault":null,
            "c_rolepermissionid":null,
            "c_objecttype":1
        }
    }'
```

and you want  to convert it into a JavaScript object i.e. an array format you can use

```
var data = JSON.parse(json);
```

You can use JSON.parse() to convert the data returned by the web API in array format provided the API return JSON data.

Answer (score 1):

```
var json = '{"1":{"c_roleid":null,"ObjectID":1,"c_appname":"Default","c_display":true,"c_add":null,"c_edit":null,"c_delete":null,"c_execute":null,"c_isdefault":null,"c_rolepermissionid":null,"c_objecttype":1}}';
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
```

Now you can access your JSON-array like this:

```
for(var key in obj){    
   console.log(obj[key].ObjectID); // will print 1 
}
```

In the for-loop you can access every property, like for example "c_roleid", c_appname", etc. For easier readability:

```
for(var key in obj){
var prop = obj[key],
    roleID = prop.c_roleid,
    objectID = prop.ObjectID,
    appName = prop.c_appname,
    // ...continue with variables 
    objectType = prop.c_objecttype;
}
```

For more examples see this url:
[Serializing to JSON in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191881/serializing-to-json-in-jquery)